# Word 2013 - How to create two multiple-level within one line?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

I want to create two multiple-level within one line, I'm using word 2016. It's like this:

```
A.1 (B.1). Heading 1 
  A.1.1 (B.1.1) Heading 2

A.2 (B.2). Heading 1
  A.2.1 (B.2.1) Heading 2
```

I've tried the following:

- Using caption to generate (B.1) (B.2)(B.2.1), but I have to add many new labels and the format would change;
- Using Style separator，but that didn't work, (A.1) and (B.1) can't exist at the same time.
- Using In-line Enter, can't work either